# buildするとiframeの画面が表示できない。

Tags: monaca, build

デバッガーアプリを使ってのiframeを使った画面への画面遷移は可能ですが、
buildしたデバッグではiframeへの画面は遷移できません。

恐らく、プラグインが足りないのかなとは思ってやってみたのですが、、、分かりませんでした。
全部に共通するのはpushPageなのでこちらのプラグインが足りないのでしょうか？

どなたかお詳しい方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか？
どうか宜しくお願い致します。

```html
<ons-navigator page="list.html" var="links.navi"></ons-navigator>
<ons-template id="list.html">
    <ons-page id="links-list-page">
      
      <ons-toolbar>
          <div class="center"></div>
      </ons-toolbar>
      
      <ons-list>   
        <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="item">
          <ons-row id="homepage">
            <ons-col>
              <header>
                <span class="item-title">リスト０１</span>
              </header>
            </ons-col>
          </ons-row>                          
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
      
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

```js
(function() {
    
    var isAndroid = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1;

    var _width = $(window).width();
    var _height = $(window).height();

    $(document).on('click', '#homepage', function() {

        ons.navigator.pushPage('_links/list01.html');

    });
  
})();
```

Comment: 不具合箇所の周辺のソースコード追記をお願いします。またOSはAndroidでしょうか。

Comment: レス頂きまして、有り難うございます。Androidです。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: iframeタグとiframeタグ周辺のコードが見当たらないのですが……。user7461さんも仰っていますが不具合箇所のコードが分からないと回答を付ける事が出‌​来ません。上記コードだけですと単なるOnsenUIの遷移で終わってしまいます。あと遷移なのですが、スコープが足りない気がします。スコープを付けるか「lin‌​ks.navi.pushPage('_links/list01.html');」かと思われます。コメント内のコード挿入が上手くいかず。orz

Comment: Sieg さん
おっしゃる通りpushPage('_links/list01.html');でした。厳密に言うと『アンダーバー』がついた事でandroidではコメントと同様の処理をされた様です。

Comment: user7461さんやSiegさんが仰っているように、iFrameの不具合周辺のコードを出してください。これでは回答することは難しいです...

Comment: >> Middleさん
ご記入有難うございます。
 2月25日 9:27 にも返答しましたが、リンク先指定の際、ディレクトリ名の先頭に『_(アンダーバー)』が入っていたのが原因でした。この内容でcloseとします。